# How do you implement OverlayItem to be draggable? (Using ItemizedIconOverlays if possible)

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have POIs showing up on the map, using OverlayItem and ItemizedIconOverlay (an  ItemizedIconOverlay list of OverlayItems). I want to be able to drag these markers around and place them different locations on a map. How would you do this on on osmdroid?

I am using OSMDroid 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Check out this SO question [Unable to implement onTouchEvent (Drag & Drop) with Osmdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986025/unable-to-implement-ontouchevent-drag-drop-with-osmdroid)

You can also check [Osmdroid issue 225](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=225) where they talk about this.